# Use WHERE clause with instances in hql

Tags: hql

How to select a record from a table using WHERE clause and comparing instances (patient)

```
    public History findHistory(Patient patient) { History model=null;
    Session sesion=util.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    String sql="FROM History h WHERE h.patients=" + patient;

    try{
        sesion.beginTransaction();
        model=(History) sesion.createQuery(sql).uniqueResult();

        sesion.beginTransaction().commit();

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        sesion.beginTransaction().rollback();
    }
    return model;
}
```

That throws a queryException #1562
e.queryString="FROM entidad.Historia h WHERE h.pacientes=entidad.Paciente@3ad3a221"
e.detailMessage="unexpected char: '@'"

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that concatenating patient like you do will just append patient.toString(), which in your case is the default implementation (i.e. classname@hashcode) and it is no use for Hibernate to find out which data to retrieve in the DB.

You need to bind the parameter, first:

```
String sql = "FROM History h WHERE h.patients = :patient";
```

Then

```
model = (History) sesion.createQuery(sql)
            .setParameter("patient", patient)
            .uniqueResult();
```

**Edit:**

*SQLGrammarException: could not execute query* can occurs for various reason. Try to run the generated query in SqlDeveloper (or any other tool) and see what your DB says. In your case, the last part `and .=?` cause the error. The `cross join` is Harming too. I suspect your mapping is incomplete and Hibernate can't find how to join History and Patient. Try to add something like this in History entity:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "patient")
private Patient patient;
```

Comment: Anthony, It does not work too. that throws a new exception type "SQLGrammarException". e.detailMessage="could not execute query" and e.sql="select historia0_.IdHistoria as IdHistoria32_, historia0_.Num_Historia as Num2_32_, historia0_.Fecha_Creacion as Fecha3_32_ from bc_conline.historia historia0_ cross join bc_conline.paciente pacientes1_ where historia0_.IdHistoria=pacientes1_.IdHistoria and .=?"

Comment: @user3674442 I edited my answer and added some clarification and clues for your error.